# Cisco Router, Port Forwarding, ACL ordering

Tags: cisco, router, nat, acl, port-forwarding

I'm new CCNA learner here. 
If I have the following access list:

```
access-list 101 permit ip 10.10.0.0 0.0.255.255 any

access-list 101 deny tcp host 10.10.0.1 eq 443 any

access-list 101 deny tcp host 10.10.0.1 eq 25 any
```

Am I correct to say the last 2 entries will be ignored since the top entry would permit all source in the 10.10.0.0/16 subnet?

I'm trying to follow the article :  https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000533

The article instructed to add deny entries after there's already existing permit entry that would allow all the hosts. Can somebody shade light on this? thanks!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The access list is evaluated in order, and it is exited on the first match.

In your particular example, if the address being evaluated is in the `10.10.0.0/16` range, it will match the first entry, and the ACL evaluation will stop, so that the following ACL entries are not considered.